# General solution to PDE $xu_x + yu_y = 2xy$, why using characterics in non-parametric form I get an incorrect general solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, paradoxes

I am trying to solve the PDE

\begin{align}
xu_x + yu_y = 2xy
\end{align}

using the method of characteristics. So the characteristic equations are

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{du}{2xy}
\end{align}

Considering the first and second equation we get

\begin{align}
x = c_1y,\quad c_1\,\text{constant}
\end{align}

Considering the second and third equation we get

\begin{align}
2xy = u + c_2,\quad c_2\text{ constant}
\end{align}

therefore the general solution is given by
\begin{align}
u(x, y) = 2xy - f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right), \quad f\text{ arbitrary function}
\end{align}

However if I substituite this solution in the PDE I get
\begin{align}
xu_x + yu_y = 4xy\,(?)
\end{align}

By the other hand, if I write down the characteristic equations parametrically, i.e

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{ds} &= x \\
\frac{dy}{ds} &= y \\
\frac{du}{ds} &= 2xy
\end{align}

from the first two I get
\begin{align}
x = Ae^s \quad\text{ and }\quad y = Be^s,\quad A,\,B \text{ constants}
\end{align}
Eliminating the parameter $s$ we get
\begin{align}
(*)\qquad \frac{x}{y} = \frac{A}{B} = C,\quad C\text{ constant}
\end{align}
Then to solve for $u$
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{ds} &= 2xy = 2ABe^{2s}\quad \text{ since } x = Ae^s,\quad y = Be^s
\end{align}
Integrating
\begin{align}
\quad u &= e^{2s}AB + D,\quad D \text{ constant} \\
\end{align}
Now since $xy = ABe^{2s}$, and using (*) we put $D = f(x/y)$, it follows
\begin{align}
u = xy + f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)
\end{align}
and this is the solution since subtituing in the PDE I get an identity.

Why am I getting the incorrect answer with the first method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xu_x + yu_y = 2xy$$
You wrote :

$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{du}{2xy}\quad $is OK.

$x = c_1y\quad $ is OK.

$2xy = u + c_2\quad$ is false.

From $\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{du}{2xy}\quad\implies\quad 2x\,dy=du$.

Then you try to integrate. But $\quad \int 2x\,dy\neq 2xy+c\quad$ because $x$ is not constant. Without writting explicitly the function $x(y)$ you cannot integrate.  ,

HINT : $\quad 2c_1y\,dy=du$

Answer (score 0):

The solution to $\frac{du}{2xy}=\frac{dy}{y}$ is not $u+c_2=2xy$. You cannot integrate $\frac{du}{dy}=2x$ treating $x$ as a constant. In fact, as you've shown before, $x=c_1y$ along a characteristic curve, hence
$$
\frac{du}{dy}=2c_1y \implies u=c_1y^2+c_2=xy+c_2,
$$
therefore
$$
u=xy+f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right).
$$